# Add Image Tag to Checkbox Input Field with Rails 4 and Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using Rails 4, Simple_Form and Bootstrap 3, I am trying to get my output HTML look like this to work with some front end styling:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input value="0" type="hidden" name="member[remember_me]">
    <label class="boolean optional" for="member_remember_me">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
        <i class="input-helper"></i>
          Keep me signed in
    </label>
</div>
```

In my form, I have this:

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, class: 'checkbox inline', type: 'checkbox', as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
```

And I cannot figure out how to get the image tag to show up inside the input field. What I get when the form is generated is this (missing the image tag):

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input value="0" type="hidden" name="member[remember_me]">
    <label class="boolean optional" for="member_remember_me">
      <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="member[remember_me]" id="member_remember_me">Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

I've tried this block that I thought should do it, but alas, no:

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, class: 'checkbox inline', type: 'checkbox', as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? do %>
  <i class="input-helper"></i>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions? Do I need to write a custom wrapper to get the image tag to show?

Answer (score 0):

One option to put content inside any rails tag is to use

```
 "#{image_tag('filename.png')}".html_safe
```

in place of the text, or using `raw()`.