# How to use image_tag as checkboxes (with simple_form and paperclip)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I would like to display a collection of instances with checkboxes. This instances are images so instead of displaying there id I would like to display their images. I'm using paperclip, so the basic usage is `image_tag model.image.url`

This is my code (according to this source: [Add Image Tag to Checkbox Input Field with Rails 4 and Simple Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138715/add-image-tag-to-checkbox-input-field-with-rails-4-and-simple-form)):

```
 = f.input_field :inspiration_image_ids, 
   :collection => InspirationImage.all.each {|i| "#{image_tag('image.url')}".html_safe }, 
   :include_blank => '(All)', 
   :multiple => true, 
   :selected => [''], 
   as: :check_boxes
```

Even with specifying the `image_tag` I still have this  output :
[image]

and this is more or less what I'd like :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map, not each.

```
InspirationImage.all.map {|i| image_tag(i.url).html_safe },
```

Also I made it `(i.url)` instead of the literal `("image.url")` string, and just using plain old image_tag should work, no need to wrap it in a string.